# Can't use perl WWW::Mechanize to tick checkboxes

Tags: javascript, perl, web-scraping, mechanize

I am making a webscraper using perl WWW::Mechanize. My problem is the site that I am scraping is using javascript a bit too much. I am logging in using credentials, Then traversing to custom search using `$mech->follow_link(url)`.

The problem starts from here. I am landing on to a page where I have to select one checkbox and one radiobutton from a javascript enabled dropdownlist. I am stuck at this point.

The part of html is as below. When I am using `$mech->tick('cs-MajorIndustryGroup')`, I am getting an error

```
Can't call method "find_input" on an undefined value
```

Comment: scraping with lots of JS - maybe [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) can help! :)

Comment: try reverse engineering the JS requests, see what they do and imitate them using simple POST / GET requests

Answer (score 5):

`WWW::Mechanize` doesn't support JavaScript. You could try some of these modules:

- [`Gtk2::WebKit::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Gtk2%3a%3aWebKit%3a%3aMechanize)
- [`Win32::IE::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aIE%3a%3aMechanize)
- [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)
- [`WWW::Scripter`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aScripter)
- [`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aSelenium).

For more information see [`WWW::Mechanize::FAQ`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript).