# WWW::Mechanize: Unable to find Form

Tags: html, forms, perl, www-mechanize

I'm trying to automate logging in to a website. The website is https://www.remind.com/log_in. Using `dump_forms` gives no forms on the page. I tried using this to submit the form anyway, but this fails to compile:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $ua = WWW::Mechanize -> new();
my $remind = 'https://www.remind.com/log_in';
$ua -> get ($remind);
$ua -> form_number(1);
my $uid = 'user@name.com';
$ua->field("uid", $uid );
my $password = 'passcode';
$ua->field("password", $password);
```

But this fails. Here is the error:
`Can't call method "value" on an undefined value`

I'm at a loss as to what the problem is.

Comment: You should show your code using the "value" method... :-)

Comment: I just added my whole code so far. I don't use the "value" method. At least I think I don't

Comment: Some options for Javascript are listed in [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655231/cant-use-perl-wwwmechanize-to-tick-checkboxes).  For one thing, [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.79/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) that you ask about is certainly a solution -- then the browser does it for you.  There's more, as well.

Comment: Firefox can autofill my username and password. I'm still having trouble finding the log in button. `click_button(n=>1)` terminates the code with this error: 3 elements found for `//*[translate(local-name(.), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = "button" or (translate(local-name(.), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = "input" and @type="submit")][1] at test.pl line 10.`. However, the login button as well as the "?" button are highlighted red in the tab (I used `autoclose_tab( 0 )` to observe this).

Answer (score 5):

Probably `$ua -> form_number(1);` is failing, since the page you are trying to scrape (https://www.remind.com/log_in) has no forms in it...

You should analyze the page, looking at it's source code ([view-source:https://www.remind.com/log_in](http://view-source:https://www.remind.com/log_in)) ... :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a form, but with no name. The page has <form> and </form> in its html, but I'm a newbie to HTML.

Comment: Are you really sure? I don't see any <form></form>, with or without a name, on that page source... :-(

Comment: Yes, there is no form in there. It's all generated client-side. Scraping this without a JS engine is going to be hard.

Comment: ah, well. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I found a module JavaScript::Engine. Could this help?

Comment: You could use for example *PhantomJS* (http://phantomjs.org/) or *Extracty* (https://extracty.com/)...

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/JE/lib/JavaScript/Engine.pm ? You can give it a try... Be warned it will not be such a simple job as with WWW::Mechanize... :-(

Comment: Perhaps www::mechanize::Firefox would do the job?